# Show that the given series in Uniformly convergent

Tags: uniform-convergence

Show that the series $$1+{e^{-2x}\over2^2-1}-{e^{-4x}\over4^2-1}+{e^{-6x}\over6^2-1}-\cdot\cdot\cdot$$

is uniformly convergent for all real $x\ge0.$

I tried applying the Dirichlet's theorem to the problem. The given series is $$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^{n-1}e^{-2nx}\over (2n)^2-1}$$

The summation $S(x)$ can be shown to be bounded. Also, for a fixed $x\geq 0,$ the sequence $\displaystyle \frac{e^{-2nx}}{ (2n)^2-1}$ is positive and monotonically decreasing. How do I show that this sequence converges uniformly to $0$ ?

I need some clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is the Weierstrass M-test:

> Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f_n:D\to \mathbb{R}.$ Suppose that for each $f_n,$ there exists $M_n\in
>  \mathbb{R}$ such that $| f_n (x) | \leq M_n$ for all $x\in D$ and
>   $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} M_n < \infty.$ Then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(x)$
>   converges uniformly on $D.$

Proof: Let $\epsilon>0.$ Since $\sum M_n$ converges, there exists an $N$ such that $\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} M_k < \epsilon.$ Now $$\sup_{x\in D} \left| \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} f_k(x) \right| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \sup_{x\in D} |f_k(x)| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} M_k < \epsilon.$$ Thus the series converges uniformly on $D.$

Now can you find such $M_n$ for your series?

Comment: i know about the M-test. how do i find such a convergent sequence ?

Comment: @AmanMittal Well can you first bound the terms of your series? Then check if these bounds have a convergent sum.

Comment: the terms are all $\le 1$

Comment: i think the terms are $\le {1\over {4n^2-1}}$

Comment: @AmanMittal Yes, $M_n = \frac{1}{4n^2-1}$ is a good bound. Now can you check that $\sum M_n < \infty $ ?

Comment: yeah, using the comparison test with $1\over n^2$ the series $\sum M_n$ should be convergent. That proves the question. Right ?

Comment: @AmanMittal Yes that is correct.